# How to print more lines?

Tags: python

So, this is my code:

```
file = open("save_file.txt")

for each_line in file:
    s = {}
    (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = each_line.split(";")
file.close()
print(s['name'])
print(s['race'])
print(s['class'])
print(s['FOR'])
print(s['INT'])
print(s['DES'])
print(s['name'])
```

The `save_file.txt`:

```
Nome: d;Raça: Humano;Classe: Mago;FOR: 5;INT: 7;DES: 5
Nome: g;Raça: umano;Classe: Mo;FOR: 56;INT: 47;DES: 85
```

When I start the program, the program only print the second line. How can I print the two or more lines?

Comment: Print `line.split(";")` and check the number of values returned

Comment: provide the input/line on what this issue is occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program is just printing the second line, it will be because you are overwriting the dictionary on every iteration of the loop, and then printing only after the final iteration of the loop. Try something like this:

```
file = open("save_file.txt")

for each_line in file:
    s = {}
    (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = each_line.split(";")
    print(s['name'])
    print(s['race'])
    print(s['class'])
    print(s['FOR'])
    print(s['INT'])
    print(s['DES'])
    print(s['name'])
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly you are creating a new empty `dict` for every line in the file, so `s` could only ever contain the values from the last line in the file. To store values from multiple lines you need to move the initialization of `s` outside of the `for` loop.
- Secondly, if you want each of the keys in your `dict` to contain multiple string values then you will need to store them in a `list` or some other kind of sequence. I'd recommend using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which would allow you to automatically populate missing keys with empty lists:

---

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ...

# missing keys will be automatically populated with empty lists
s = defaultdict(list)
keys = ['name', 'race', 'class', 'FOR', 'INT', 'DES']

for each_line in file:

    # in order to store multiple values under each key, append them to
    # a list
    for kk, vv in zip(keys, each_line.split(";")):
        s[kk].append(vv)

# ...
```